# how to check if an object has at least one true value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array that looks like following

```
values = {de: true, en: false, nl: false, pl: false, ru: false}
```

I using the array to make a layout change in jsx, how can I check if the array has at least one true value in JSX,

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your "array"'s syntax is invalid. Arrays do not have key-value pairs.

Comment: And during your research you haven't found a solution for this task (after fixing the syntax of the array)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that `values` is actually an object, check if `.some` of the `Object.values` of the object are true:

```js
const values = {de: true, en: false, nl: false, pl: false, ru: false};

const someTruthy = Object.values(values).some(val => val === true);
console.log(someTruthy);
```

(if the only truthy value is true, you can use `(val => val)` instead)

Comment: Cool shorthand with `val => val` but I would honestly stick with `val => val === true` even if the only truthy value is `true` as it's more clear to future readers (including yourself!)