# how to go through react state variable array and determine if it has one true value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a state variable like the following

```
const Home = ({ t, i18n, history }) => {
  const [otherStudiosAvailable, setOtherStudiosAvailable] = useState([]);

  const studios = ["de", "fr", "pl", "en", "nl", "ru"];
  const otherStudios = studios.filter(item => {
    return item !== i18n.language;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let others = [];
    for (const studio of otherStudios) {
      checkForAvailableAgent(
        `sales_${studio}`,
        "Linktostudio",
        "serviceID"
      )
        .then(res => {
          others[studio] = res;
          setOtherStudiosAvailable(others);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("an error happened.");
        });
    }
   }, []);

}

{otherStudiosAvailable.indexOf(true) ? (

    <Button
      variant="success"
       onClick={e => callBtnClick("flag")}
    >
    Other studios available
    </Button>

    ) : ("")
   }
```

I need to have a conditional check in JSX based on otherStudiosAvailable, if it has at least one true value

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if otherStudiosAvailable has at least one true show the button otherwise don't show anything

Comment: i think the condition should be otherStudiosAvailable.indexOf(true) !== -1,
because if the true exists in the first element (index 0 ) the result will be false

Comment: How is this different to your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336179/how-to-check-if-an-array-has-at-least-one-true-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually indeOf would return -1 in case if true is not present in the array
but the truthy value of -1 is true, hence you need to  explicitly check if its not equal to -1(which indicates the presence of the element)
Object.values(otherStudiosAvailable) returns the array of values present in this object

```
 {Object.values(otherStudiosAvailable).indexOf(true)!==-1 ? (

    <Button
       variant="success"
      onClick={e => callBtnClick("flag")}
    >
    Other studios available
    </Button>

    ) : ("")
}
```

Comment: console.log(otherStudiosAvailable) gives                                                                      en: true
fr: false
nl: false
pl: false
ru: false  however I always get false in the indexOf(true)

Comment: does it return an array of objects ?
my answer is valid in case otherStudiosAvailable is an array of values(not objects)

Comment: upon further inspection, i understand that the otherStudiosAvailable is an object
i've updated my answer based on it

Comment: I get the TypeError: otherStudiosAvailable.values(...).indexOf is not a function

Comment: @akano1 sorry my bad
its Object.values(otherStudiosAvailable)
i've updated my answer, this should definitely fix the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution

```
    {otherStudiosAvailable.indexOf(true)!==-1 && (

    <Button
       variant="success"
      onClick={e => callBtnClick("flag")}
    >
    Other studios available
    </Button>

    )
}
```